# Annunity calculation with and without tax

Tags: finance, economics

I'm doing a annunity calculation:

```
    payment = 331880*(  0,002458333 /( 1-(1+0,002458333)^-84) )
```

This will return me the payment per. month of the loan (4.337,76), over a period of 84 months.

Now, what i would like to know is what the payment per. month will be after a deduction of 33% tax on the interest rate. In the previous example `(4.337,76)` the result will be `4.236,91`.

Etc. Loan before tax:

```
    Month       Interest        Payment         Total
    0           815,87          3.561,88        4.377,76
    1           807,12          3.570,64        4.377,76
    2           798,34          3.579,42        4.377,76
```

Loan after tax:

```
    Month       Interest        Payment         Total
    0           546,63          3.561,88        4.108,52
    1           540,77          3.570,64        4.111,41
    2           534,89          3.579,42        4.114,30
```

As you can see, the deduction is made to the interest, which is deducted by the 33%. ( Month 1: (851,86*0.67) = 546,63

I'm certain that there is a fancy method of doing this in the annunity calculation, without having to calculate a full table, fetching every single interest and doing the calculation there. I JUST cant find it!

Ive tried to deduct the 33% tax on the initial nominal interest rate
0.02458 * 0.67. But the results are not satisfying.

The formula for the anunity-calculation is as follows:
(Not enough rep to post image. Link is: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/9/0/49004d321caf393384ee4f211622a12c.png )

Where

```
Y = The amount to pay pr. period
G = Total amount to loan
r = The interest rate in decimals
n = the amount of payments
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The thing to do is to understand how the formula in your first display was worked out, then try to follow the same logic in the new situation.

Comment: Hi Gerry, thank you for answering. As i point out in the question, i am more than certain that there is a smarter way to achieve this, by using the original formula (I've updated the question with an image of the formula) - But honestly, i cant figure it out, and since this is not a school thing, i unfortunately cant ask any clever persons - other than you guys. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: By the way, your formula has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Hi Gerry, thank you. I've updated my question.